# What to include in random structure? lmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

Should we still have trial number in the linear mixed effects model as a random effect even if the trial order is randomized not only for each participant but each session? I included participants as a random effect but not sure about whether trial should also be included.

```
Session 1

           Participant A                  Participant B
trial     Prob        RT                    Prob    RT
trial 1   2           360                   1       420
trial 2   1           450                   2       345
trial 3   1           410                   2       532
trial 4   1           320                   1       295

...

Session 2

           Participant A                  Participant B

trial 1    2    234                      1   357
trial 2    1    362                      1   362
trial 3    1    325                      2   243
trial 4    2    284                      2   284
...

model <- lmer(RT ~ Prob*Session + (1|Participant)
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data and your `lmer` code? Is trial the same as Session?

Comment: hope it helped.

Comment: can you add sample data `dput(dataset)` and `lmer` code?

Comment: How many values of item are there? And which variable is it in your sample data?

Comment: By item I mean trials and I have 1000 trials.

Comment: So each participant has  data from 1000 trials? How many individuals in the sample?

Comment: Yes, 1000 trials per participant and 50 participants